# Whats the difference between using the clear command and mqget api call to clear a queue?

Tags: queue, message-queue, ibm-mq, mq

While clearing the queue in WebSphere MQ, whats the difference between using the clear command and mqget API call ?

Comment: What queue?  An IBM Websphere MQ queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just verified that the CLEAR command also reduces the size of the queue file back to that of any empty queue.

With Clear QL, WMQ discards the queue file as well and recreates it.  Normally, a queue file's size is not reduced until after some interval of the file space not being used.

I remember having to do this when we had a queue fill up the disk.  rather than process the messages, we CLEARed the queue to free up the disk space at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

The CLEAR command issues a single command which clears the queue, while Clearing using the MQGET command reads the queue until it's empty.

Practically, one can Clear using MQGET without having to acquire an exclusive lock on the queue. On the other hand, if the queue is in use somewhere, the CLEAR command will fail.

The IBM documentation lists the difference as follows:

- If you use the CLEAR command, all of the messages are cleared from the queue. However, if the queue is already opened exclusively by another application or if the queue contains uncommitted messages, the command fails immediately and none of the messages are cleared.
- If you use the MQGET API call, the messages are got from the queue until no more messages are available. However, MQGET does not recognize uncommitted messages, which means that there could still be uncommitted messages on the queue. Also, the command might fail if the queue is already exclusively opened by another application.

Comment: So, you could say that the CLEAR command is safer because it will not empty an in-use queue.

Comment: Sort of. CLEAR fails when there is *any* handle on the queue, including PUT handles.  So if a queue fills because the consumer died and you still have at least one producer attached, clear will fail. In this scenario, CLEAR is no safer than GET but it's the only thing that works.

Comment: Just updated the answer to include info from IBM about uncommitted messages.